# I try import maya model(.OBJ) to Blender

Tags: rendering

[image]

in EEVEE render the model seems broken

[image]

But in Cycles it turns good model
, what did i miss?

(and I apologize for my broken English)

---

Thanks every one! to your comments my problem is solved.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE :). Please [upload your .blend file here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look.

Comment: Looks like flipped normals. Eevee works with backface culling on. And when the face points in the wrong direction then it gets rendered invisible. In Edit mode with all geometry selected try Mesh/Normals/Recalculate Outside. Also hotkey Shift N

Comment: try exporting and importing with fbx. much better option.

Comment: Also the materials in OBJ from maya will keep transparent option, you have to change it to opaque or it will seems that it is seethrou.

Comment: @Tiles Please, consider posting this as an answer with some images :). The comment section is kind of hard to navigate.

Comment: I had this issue when I tried viewing one of my models in LookDev mode, which uses the same settings as Eevee. Try turning your material blending mode to Opaque. That fixed it for me.

Comment: @Jachym Michal, i would when i am sure if that's the cause. Just found out that nowadays everything is treated as double sided rendering in Blender. So the cause must be something else.